# Shell Script: How to read standard output of a program from console

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to write a shell script which gives different inputs to a program and checks the outputs whether they are expected results or not. In conclusion of these tests, I decide whether there is a bug in my executable program.

I run my program over shell script with `./my_program arg1 arg2` (arg1 and arg2 are command line arguments of my program). After that, the script shell constantly gives different inputs to `my_program` in order to test it and in controlling terminal (or console) standard outputs are iteratively writen like this:

```
Connection established.
Intermediate result is expected_intermediate_result1
Final result is expected_result1
Connection established.
Intermediate result is expected_intermediate_result2
Final result is expected_result2
```

And it goes on. For each input, its output is known. So they are matched before.

When connection fails: it is writen `Error in connection!`
Or result may be wrong:

```
Connection established.
Intermediate result is result1
Final result is wrong_result1
```

Apart from giving input, the script has another purpose: check the result.

So I want to read outputs from console and compare them with expected result in order to determine the case in which there is an inconsistency.

I want your assistance to edit this code:

```
while read console line-by-line
if the line is other than expected result
store this case to text file
done
```

Some cautions:
I don't want to use `expect`. I just want to read outputs of the program which is writen in console. I don't use log file so search in a file (`grep`) will not be used.

Thanks for assistence!

Comment: Why don't you want to use expect? This is exactly what it's intended for. Homework or something?

Comment: This is not a homework. As far as I know, in order to use expect, I should download a library. For security issues, downloading anything to the computer on which I am working is forbidden. If expect is only solution, then I have to use expect and find a way to use it. So let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
./my_program arg1 arg2  |
grep -Fxq "Final result is expected_result1" || { printf 'Failed: "arg1 arg2" -> "expected_result1"\n'; exit 1; }
```

If not then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide a more concrete example.